# Создать массив из массивов: реально ли?

Tags: массивы, java

Потребовалось вернуть два массива, появилась идея сделать массив из массивов:

```
String[] names ={"dsgsdfh", "sd vsd"};
String[] values ={"dfs xdfs d", "sisd nas"};
Array[] NV = {names,values};
```

Не прошло.

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to Array.

**Вопрос**: реально ли создать массив из массивов?

p.s. *Я не спрашиваю как вернуть два массива, я спрашиваю про создание массива из массивов*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тогда используйте коллекции.

```
String[] names ={"dsgsdfh", "sd vsd"};
    String[] values ={"dfs xdfs d", "sisd nas"};

    ArrayList<String[]> allArrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();      
    allArrays.add(names);
    allArrays.add(values);

    for (String a[]:allArrays){
        for (String b:a){
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
Сколько угодно массивов вставляйте
```

Answer (score 4):

Вполне реально, замените Array[] на String[][]

```
public class Arrays {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] one = {"one", "two", "three"};
    String[] two = {"for", "five", "six"};
    String[][] three = {one, two};

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(three));
}
```

}

Comment: Я бы не назвал двумерку двумя массивами. На то она и двумерка :)

Тем более не получится следующие: 

    String[] names ={"dsgsdfh", "sd vsd"};
    String[] values ={"dfs xdfs d", "sisd nas"};
    String[] aaa = {"fd", "igdpioasegpo"};
    String[][] NV = {names,values, aaa}; 

Да, можно просто заменить [][] на [][][]. Но если мы изначально не знаем, сколько массивов придётся вписать в массив, то способ провалится!

Comment: @danpetruk,  да, ладно, не получится? А Вы пробовали?

Comment: @Niki-Timofe по логике не должно

Comment: @danpetruk, а на практике?

Comment: @Niki-Timofe чудеса случаются. Получилось (3 массива в [][]). Остаётся понять почему...

Answer (score 1):

[[@mage](/users/4333/mage)](/users/4333/mage) прав, но это просто двумерный массив. А если массив из массивов,
то лучше так:

```
public int 1-st
public String 2-nd
public double 3-rd
public float 4-d

 public massiv(int 1-st, String 2-nd, double 3-rd, float 4-d)
      {
        this.1-st = 1-st;
        this.2-nd = 2-nd;
        this.3-rd = 3-rd; 
        this.4-d = res;
      }
```

Далее:

```
 massiv[] big_array = new massiv[7];
big_array[0] = new massiv(значение,значение,значение, значение);
big_array[1] = new massiv(значение,значение,значение, значение);
big_array[2] = new massiv(значение,значение,значение, значение);
big_array[3] = new massiv(значение,значение,значение, значение);
.
.
.
и т.д.
```

Comment: Кстати знак - в переменных запрещён

Comment: В курсе! Просто чтобы показать что там что то должно быть!